# Oracle SQL Toad

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving many duplicates when I check it with my Oracle SQL query. I want to select my based on my highest count from my query which I wrote

```
select distinct 
npa,--,nxx
state, country, time_zone, count(*)  
from npanxx 
where time_zone is not null and time_zone <> '0' --and npa = '270' 
group by npa
--, nxx
, state, country, time_zone
order by npa
```

This query let me see which npa has highest amount of columns and based on that I want to choose max(count(*)) but it didn't work. I tried something

```
select distinct 
npa,--,nxx
state, country, time_zone, count(*)  
from npanxx 
where time_zone is not null and time_zone <> '0' --and npa = '867' 
group by npa
--, nxx
, state, country, time_zone
having count(*) = (select max(count(*)) from npanxx where time_zone is not null and time_zone <> '0' --and npa = '867' 
group by npa, state, country, time_zone) 
order by npa, count(*) desc
```

But this query gave me just one row which is the highest of all in whole row but I need highest count(*) of all npa which I am getting from my first query.
Thank you in advance for the help.
I am looking for something like this:
From the first query I receive this result

```
NPA   State  Country  Time_zone   Count(*) Column 
052    MX         MX           4             410
052    MX         MX           5             1620
052    MX         MX           6             20980
206    WA         US           4             27889
206    WA         US           5             60
```

and I need to have an answer like this

```
NPA   State  Country  Time_zone   Count(*) Column 

052     MX  MX             6            20980
206     WA  US             4            27889
```

Comment: Can you please better format your code; can you even add an example of data and desired result?

Comment: From the first query I receive this result
NPA   State  Country  Time_zone   Count(*) Column 
052    MX       MX        4          410
052    MX       MX        5          1620
052    MX       MX        6          20980
206    WA       US        4          27889
206    WA       US        5          60
and I need to have an answer like this
NPA   State  Country  Time_zone   Count(*) Column 
052     MX MX            6            20980
206     WA US            4                 27889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand what you're trying to do, but believe you're trying to find which state, country, time_zone within each npa has the highest count.  What you need is to get the current npa from the outer query into the inner query.  I believe you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT  
   npa,
   state,
   country,
   time_zone,
   count(*)
FROM
   npanxx outer
WHERE
   time_zone IS NOT NULL AND
   time_zone <> 0
GROUP BY
   npa,
   state,
   country,
   time_zone
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = (
      SELECT
         MAX(count(*))
      FROM
         npanxx inner
      WHERE
         time_zone IS NOT NULL AND
         time_zone <> 0 AND
         outer.npa = inner.npa
      GROUP BY
         state,
         country,
         time_zone)
ORDER BY
   npa,
   count(*) DESC
```

Now, if multiple state/country/time_zones within an npa have the same number, you'll get multiple rows for that npa.

Anyway, my best guess for now on what you're trying to do.

Comment: That exactly what I meant. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I actually add one more column of nxx into this query and it start to duplicate again.

NPA      NXX      State    Country      TimeZone    Count(*)
878       888         PA         USA               7                23
878       201         PA         USA               7                22
878       228         PA         USA               7                22
878       700         PA         USA               5                10

and I want only highest count(*) which is with 23.
Any help on this??

Answer (score 0):

A much easier solution is to use an analytic function:

```
select 
    npa,
    state, 
    country,
    time_zone,
    count(*) over (partition by symbol) cnt
from npanxx 
where time_zone is not null 
order by cnt desc;
```

Hint: It is a good idea to set database constraints immediately as part of your table design. That avoids letting the users entering duplicates, and as an extra it speeds up your queries (as Oracle uses an implicit unique index to enforce unique constraints).